# Access resource bundle outside struts action class

Tags: struts2, struts-1, resourcebundle

There are several ways to handle resource bundle using Struts 2.3 framework. This includes using certain UI tags in the View class or `getText()` method in your Action class.

However, there is no straight-forward mechanism to access this resource bundle in a java class or any other class except View and Action.

I found two ways to access it in a java class,however, they fail to completely replace the old `MessageResources` of Struts 1.2 framework.

Following are the two ways with drawback of each

1. Using `ResourceBundle` class of `java.util` package.

   ```
   Locale locale = (Locale)request.getSession().getAttribute(ConstantsFnl.LOCALE_KEY);
   ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(bundle,locale);
   message = rb.getString(key);
   ```

   The drawback with this approach is you cannot pass an array of arguments which can be replaced in your message text.This functionality was present in Struts 1.2 with `MessageReosurces`.
2. Using `DefaultTextProvider` of Struts 2.3 framework.

   ```
   DefaultTextProvider dtp = new DefaultTextProvider();
   return dtp.getText(key, (String[])params);
   ```

Though this approach gives you a way to pass an array of arguments to be replaced in your message text, it does not give you a mechanism to specify the locale or specify the bundle to be searched.Again,this functionality is present in Struts 1.2 with `MessageResources` class.

Looking for an optimum approach.Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use methods found in:

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.LocalizedTextUtil
```

Comment: @kozla13: Example for what exactly?

Comment: @AleksandrM How to use LocalizedTextUtil ?

Comment: @kozla13: What do you need javadoc or something? http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/xwork-core/apidocs/index.html.

Comment: updated url for api/javadoc: http://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/index.html